# uses-library tag in AndroidManifest.xml vs useLibrary in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-9.0-pie

I want to build a project, that uses Apache HTTP client, for Android P.
As far as I understand, there are 2 ways to do this:

**First via AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
 <application
     ...
     <uses-library
         android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
         android:required="false" />
 </application>
```

**Second via build.gradle:**

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Are these ways equivalent?

Why android.useLibrary command in build gradle DOES NOT add the uses-library tag in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: "I want to build a project, that uses Apache http client" -- use [the independent library](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html).

Answer (score 1):

Extending what CommonsWare commented.

Use gradle dependency to use apache http client, don't modify `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Modify your `build.gradle` as

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
}
```

Comment: Please explain **why** all that should be done, and try to format your answer properly

Answer (score -1):

Adding this to AndroidManifest.xml should notify Android at runtime these classes exist:

```
<uses-library
      android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
      android:required="false" />
```

Reference: [specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2705)

The build.gradle declaration makes sure the library is available at compile time.

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Reference: [behavior-apache-http-client](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-apache-http-client)